# How Can $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Minimization with Linear Equality Constraints (Basis Pursuit / Sparse Representation) Be Formulated as Linear Programming?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, sparsity

### Problem Statement

Show how the $L_1$-sparse reconstruction problem:
$$\min_{x}{\left\lVert x\right\rVert}_1 \quad \text{subject to} \; y=Ax$$
can be reduced to a linear programming problem of form similar to:
$$\min_{u}{b^Tu} \quad \text{subject to} \; Gu=h, Cu\le e.$$
We can assume that $y$ belongs to the range of $A$, typically because $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is full-rank with $m\lt n$.

### What I've Got

I have never worked with linear programming before, and though I think I understand the basics, I have no experience with this kind of reduction. So far, I have tried understanding the problem geometrically: any $x$ in the solution set to $y=Ax$ can be written as the sum of some arbitrary solution $x_0$ and a vector $v$ in the null space of $A$, so the solution set is a shifted copy of the null space. We are trying to expand the $L_1$-ball (or hyper-diamond? I don't know what to call it) until one of the corners hits that shifted subspace. My problem is, I don't know how to express that formally.

The best I can think of is to use a method similar to [Converting Sum of Infinity Norm and $ {L}_{1} $ Norm to Linear Programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680524) and let $t_i=\left\lvert x_i\right\rvert, i=1\dots n$ and rewrite the objective as:
$$\min_{t}{1^Tt} \quad \text{subject to} \; x\le t, -x\le t, y=Ax$$
But then $x$ is still floating around in the problem, which doesn't match the desired form (and isn't implementable with MATLAB's `linprog` function, which I will have to do later). And even if we find such a $t$, recovering the underlying $x$ doesn't seem straightforward to me either.

Am I even moving in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks good. Except you may want to write $\min_{x,t}$ instead of just $\min_{t}$. Just plug it in your LP solver and retrieve the solution for $x$ (both $x$ and $t$ will be decision variables).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you! I hadn't thought to include x in my decision variable; I assumed we were supposed to transform it and solve indirectly. I posted my solution as an answer.

Comment: The solution of $Ax = y$ is of the form $x = \bar{x} + V \eta$, where the columns of $V$ form a basis of the null space of $A$. Hence, one could minimize $\| V \eta + \bar{x} \|_1$, which is a lower-dimensional problem without any constraints.

Comment: @p.koch, Could you please mark an answer? Either yours or mine. But it will be better for the site to mark it.

Answer (score 16):

### Conversion of Basis Pursuit to Linear Programming

The [Basis Pursuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_pursuit) problem is given by:

$$
\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \: & \: {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \: & \: A x = b
\end{align*}
$$

#### Method A

The term $ {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} $ can written in element wise form:

$$ {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left| {x}_{i} \right| $$

Then setting $ \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq {t}_{i} $ one could write:

$$
\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{t} \: & \: \boldsymbol{1}^{T} t \\
\text{subject to} \: & \: A x = b \\
& \: \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq {t}_{i} \; \forall i
\end{align*}
$$

Since $ \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq {t}_{i} \iff {x}_{i} \leq {t}_{i}, \, {x}_{i} \geq -{t}_{i} $ then:

$$
\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{t} \: & \: \boldsymbol{1}^{T} t \\
\text{subject to} \: & \: A x = b \\
& \: {x}_{i} \leq {t}_{i} \; \forall i \\
& \: {x}_{i} \geq -{t}_{i} \; \forall i
\end{align*}
$$

Which can be farther refined:

$$
\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{t} \: & \: \boldsymbol{1}^{T} t \\
\text{subject to} \: & \: A x = b \\
  & I x - I t \preceq \boldsymbol{0} \\
- & I x - I t \preceq \boldsymbol{0}
\end{align*}
$$

Which is a Linear Programming problem.

#### Method B

Define:

$$ x = u - v, \; {u}_{i} = \max \left\{ {x}_{i}, 0 \right\}, \; {v}_{i} = \max \left\{ -{x}_{i}, 0 \right\} $$

Then the problem becomes:

$$
\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{u, v} \: & \: \sum_{i = 1}^{n} {u}_{i} + {v}_{i} \\
\text{subject to} \: & \: A \left( u - v \right) = b \\
& \: u \succeq \boldsymbol{0} \\
& \: v \succeq \boldsymbol{0}
\end{align*}
$$

Which is also a Linear Programming problem.

#### MATLAB Implementation

MATLAB Implementation is straight forward using the [`linprog()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) function.
The full code, including validation using CVX, can be found in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q1639716 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes).

##### Code Snippet - Method A

```
function [ vX ] = SolveBasisPursuitLp001( mA, vB )


numRows = size(mA, 1);
numCols = size(mA, 2);

%% vX = [vX; vT]

mAeq = [mA, zeros(numRows, numCols)];
vBeq = vB;

vF = [zeros([numCols, 1]); ones([numCols, 1])];
mA = [eye(numCols), -eye(numCols); -eye(numCols), -eye(numCols)];
vB = zeros(2 * numCols, 1);

sSolverOptions = optimoptions('linprog', 'Display', 'off');
vX = linprog(vF, mA, vB, mAeq, vBeq, [], [], sSolverOptions);
vX = vX(1:numCols);


end
```

##### Code Snippet - Method B

```
function [ vX ] = SolveBasisPursuitLp002( mA, vB )

numRows = size(mA, 1);
numCols = size(mA, 2);

% vU = max(vX, 0);
% vV = max(-vX, 0);
% vX = vU - vX;
% vUV = [vU; vV];

vF = ones([2 * numCols, 1]);

mAeq = [mA, -mA];
vBeq = vB;

vLowerBound = zeros([2 * numCols, 1]);
vUpperBound = inf([2 * numCols, 1]);

sSolverOptions = optimoptions('linprog', 'Display', 'off');

vUV = linprog(vF, [], [], mAeq, vBeq, vLowerBound, vUpperBound, sSolverOptions);

vX = vUV(1:numCols) - vUV(numCols + 1:end);


end
```

I used the code above in [Reconstruction of a Signal from Sub Sampled Spectrum by Compressed Sensing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/78143).

Comment: Nice answer. However, I think things would be clearer, if in Method A you changed the $\arg \min_{t}$ to $\arg \min_{x,t}$.

Comment: @ElmarZander, Hi. Thank you for the compliment. Feel free to +1. Regarding writing $ x $ explicitly, for some reason the convention is not write it as it is not part of the objective function but part of the constrains.

Comment: That maybe some convention, but not all conventions are necessarily good. In my view, it makes the expression incorrect as the binding of $x$ becomes unclear and considering $x$ as a free variable isn't correct as well. Furthermore, minimisation over $x$ and $t$ is what is really done in the algorithm and so also the code would better fit to formulas.

Comment: what is $t_i$ ?

Comment: @smaillis, Those are the elements of the vector $ t $.

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out! As Erwin pointed out, the formulation above is valid (save the fact that it should be optimized over x and t together). In order to write it in the form suggested by the problem, I needed to stack x and t:

$$\min_{u=[x^T\;t^T]^T}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}x\\t\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{subject to}\; \begin{bmatrix}I & -I \\ -I & -I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\t\end{bmatrix}\le\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix},\; \begin{bmatrix}A & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\t\end{bmatrix} = y,\;\begin{bmatrix}x\\t\end{bmatrix}\ge\begin{bmatrix}-\infty\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

(Please excuse my sloppy use of $0$ and $1$ for a vector/matrix of all zeros or all ones)

Comment: I have written a python implementation of BP solver using this formula here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424993/is-there-a-python-implementation-of-a-basis-pursuit-solver
It works.