# Is my optimization problem linear or convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have an optimization problem which I would like to know whether it is linear or convex.

There are three variables $x_0$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ for which the optimization problem should be minimized.

Constraint: $\sum_{i=0}^{3}x_n = 1$

Boundaries: $0 \leq x_n \leq 1$

Objective: $Minimize\ \ \ || \pmb{v_3} - (x_0\pmb{v_0} + x_1\pmb{v_1} + x_2\pmb{v_2}) ||$

where $x_0$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are scalars and $\pmb{v_0}$, $\pmb{v_1}$, $\pmb{v_2}$ and $\pmb{v_3}$ vectors of the same size.

Is my optimization problem linear or convex? And why?

Comment: What norm? Euclidean, sup, $p$...

Comment: @Renard the vectors have a size of ~10000 elements

Comment: Your constraints are linear. Norms are convex and convexity is preserved under affine transformation so your problem is convex (since you minimize). If the norm is the 1 or infinity norm, then the problem can be converted into a linear problem.

Comment: @MarcDinh Thanks for the explanation. Could you help me converting it into a linear problem for norm 1?

Comment: @MerklT You can find it here :
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639716/how-can-l-1-norm-minimization-with-linear-equality-constraints-basis-pu