# Minimum volume sphere bounding all points as a linear programming problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, computational-geometry, second-order-cone-programming

I want to find the smallest sphere which encapsulate a set of points $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

I can formulate is as

$$ \arg \min_{a \in \mathbb{R}^d, r} r \quad\quad \text{s.t.} \quad || x_i - a|| \leq r $$

Can it be formulated as a linear programming problem?
If not, is there a reasonable approximation?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639716/how-can-l-1-norm-minimization-with-linear-equality-constraints-basis-pu?rq=1

Comment: @SutanuMajumdar, I think the link is about a different norm.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem directly via [second-order cone programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming).

Other approaches are described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere

Comment: Nice. Are there resources which explains in layman words the described work there?