# Minimize the $L^1$-norm with linear equality constrain

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

How can I solve efficiently the problem:

$$\min_x \| A x \|_1 \quad \text{subject to} \; {b}^{T} x = c$$

for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, c \in \mathbb{R}$.  The matrix $A$ has independent columns.

Is there a closed form solution? Or a trick to quickly calculate $x$?

I am aware it can be solved iteratively by projected gradient descent and by other alternating methods. Yet they converge pretty slowsly.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser, great guidance. I added notes about how I can solve it now. The motivation is for simpler method then iterative gradient descent.

Comment: Have you seen this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639716/how-can-l-1-norm-minimization-with-linear-equality-constraints-basis-pu ?

Comment: @CroCo, I am aware of the linear programming method to solve this. looking for something independent of specific solver.